# Unable to compile xamarin.forms with new VS 2022 or VS2022 for mac and xcode 15

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Upgraded my VS to 17.8.0 and my VS mac to 17.6.7.  I also updated my mac to xcode 15.
Xamarin.Forms nuget package is version 5.0.0.2662

I have a xamarin.forms application that compiled just fine on the previous xcode and vs editions.  Why is this now not working.  I get the following errors

```
 : warning : ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lxml2.2', '-lz'
```

MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'System' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'System.Net.Security' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'ntdll' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'crypt32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'sspicli' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'libsecret-1.so' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'ntdll' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'advapi32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'libsecret-1.so' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'BCrypt' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'dl' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
MTOUCH : warning MT5215: References to 'kernel32' might require additional -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error MT5209 : Native linking error : warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lxml2.2', '-lz'
error MT5209 : Native linking error : framework 'System' not found

Comment: OK this is strange, if i change the link option to link all it works but i cant debug

Comment: Verify that your Xamarin.iOS version is compatible with Xcode 15. Sometimes, updates to Xcode may require updates to Xamarin.iOS to maintain compatibility. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)